# Geometric distribution of a Yule process multiplied by $e^{-\lambda s}$ converges to exponential distribution with parameter 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

If Y is a Yule process with rate $\lambda$ than I know that the generating function is 
$$F(x,t) = \frac{xe^{-\lambda t}}{1-x+xe^{-\lambda t}}$$.

Now I want to show that 
$$\lim_{s\to \infty}e^{-\lambda s}Y(s)=\epsilon$$
where $\epsilon$ has a exponential distribution with mean 1.

If I define $Z(s):=e^{-\lambda s}Y(s)$ than the generating function should be 
$$F(x,s) = \frac{xe^{-\lambda s e^{-\lambda s}}}{1-x+xe^{-\lambda s e^{-\lambda s}}}$$
But as $s\to \infty$ I get $$\frac{x}{1-x+x}=x \neq \frac{1}{1-x}$$
because $$\lim_{s \to \infty} e^{-\lambda s e^{-\lambda s}} = 1$$.

Where is my mistake?